# Spring Boot EurekaClient application is not working in external TC server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, service-discovery

I have a Spring Boot rest service. Recently, I have updated it as Discovery Client to leverage auto discovery and routing provided by spring cloud. The service is working fine when it is running from STS. But, while I'm deploying it to external TC server, it is not starting throwing the below error at catalina log.

```
24-Sep-2015 04:42:49.945 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:483)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:169)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1712)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 18 more
```

I have below dependencies in pom related to this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
.
.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- For Eureka dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- End of Eureka dependency -->
```

I have tried adding below depency also.But, no luck. Please suggest.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT:
Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
         app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Controller implementation

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ResourceController {
@RequestMapping(value="/test",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(){
        return "Service is Alive";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such error mostly result in either of these cases :-

```
a) Respective library is missing 
b) The version of library is old and do not hold respective implementation needed.
c) There is more than one version of library available in classpath and app gets stuck in deciding which to use.
```

In your case the statement says "org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig" so you should be including the one from project "org.glassfish.jersey". Pls try this:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried it, but didn't work! :(

Comment: Can you unzip the war you just built and see if this library is packaged with it and also check the TC server library path for status of this library !!!

Comment: Yes, the library is there and the application is running without any error in log. But, I'm still unable to get response from the rest url. It is throwing 404.

Comment: So your initial issue where your app was not deploying & throwing error seems working fine now. Now for your 2nd issue with rest controller you need to share details on your rest implementation for any trace.

Comment: Thanks! It has worked finally! The application was running at TC server default port e.g. 8080. I was constantly trying with the port configured in application.properties file i.e. server.port=8081